# Save all attachment from Outlook Mail with specific subjects using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want a Powershell script that is able to get me all the attachments from the email subject "Daily Headcount".

Comment: Cool. What is your question, and where are the emails stored?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Question is I want a PowerShell script that can store my outlook email  attachment with a specific email subject containing the words "Headcount"

Comment: What type of email server is Outlook connecting to for reading the emails? Usually you'd do this at the email server level rather than at the Outlook level.

Comment: @nishantdamani “I want a powershell script that…” is *not* a question

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search found this article that appears to cover what you’re looking for.

https://bronowski.it/blog/2020/09/saving-outlook-attachments-with-powershell/